# is there any way of accessing a variable inside one express route inside another different route?

Tags: node.js, express

i have this project where im populating a lists collection in database with todos in the show page of a 'board'.
This is the board showpage route

```
    app.get('/boards/:id', (req, res) => {
    Board.findById(req.params.id).populate('lists').exec(function(err, foundBoard) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            List.findById(req.params.id).populate("todos").exec(function (err, foundlist) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(foundlist);
                    res.render('show', { board: populatedboard ,list:foundlist});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the route where the variable is i want to access.i want to access and use that variable in the board show route (const listid is the variable i want to use in the board show route)

```
app.post("/boards/:id/lists/:listid/todos",function(req,res){
    Board.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundBoard) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      Todo.create(req.body.todo, function (err, newtodo) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
                    console.log(newtodo);
          List.findById(req.params.listid, function (err, foundlist) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else {
                            **const listid**= req.params.listid;
              foundBoard.todos.push(newtodo);
                            foundBoard.save();
                            res.redirect("/boards/" + foundBoard._id);
            }
          });
        }
            });
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: These are 2 totally separate functions that will never handle same request. It doesn't make sense to share data between them. You even didn't say which variable you want to use.

Comment: i want to use const listid i have mentioned

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed that. Still - this const is information attached to each of your POST requests. Each request is unrelated to other requests and should be handled separately. Why would you want to use params from one request in a completely different request? How would you be able to know which post request relates to which get request?  You need to explain business logic. It seems to me that you want to do something that requires a completely different approach than what you are trying to do.